# Detecting outlier sequences in clusters

Tags: clustering, outliers, traminer

My question is a general one:
I have sequences of categorical variables (click stream) that I analyzed using TraMineR.

I now want to conduct cluster analysis (CA) using the WeightedCluster package. An important step in CA is detecting outliers (before or after clustering). I read the package's manual, but couldn't find any reference to outlier detection. How can this be done on categorical sequences?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by outlier detection step in CA! I cannot figure out what you want to do and why this would require something specific for the clustering of sequences.

Comment: According to Hair et. al. (2013), Cluster analysis is sensitive to outliers and can distort the final solution. One option they suggest for detecting outliers empirically is with inter-object similarity. I have 1400 sequences, so my dissimilarity matrix is very large.  So how can I detect sequence outliers that I can then delete from the cluster analysis?

Comment: So you are not interested in detecting outliers in clusters, but in filtering outliers out before running a clustering algorithm. Right? I would suggest you edit your title and your question to make that clear.

Comment: It probably can be either way: or before clustering or afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first solution would be to detect outliers from the distances between the sequences and a representative sequence such as the medoid. You get the distances from the medoid using for example the `disscenter` function of `TraMineR`. (See the help page of that function.) Once you have these distances, you can define outliers as those sequences that lie at more than say 2 or 2.5 times the pseudo standard deviation from the medoid. The pseudo standard deviation is obtained with the `dissvar` function.

Alternatively, you could consider multiple representatives instead of a single one. (See [Gabadinho and Ritschard, 2013](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/publications/gr/GabadhinoRitschard-TypicalTrajectories2013.pdf).) In that case you would retain the distance of each sequence to its closest representative. I illustrate below using the 2000 sequences in the `biofam` dataset that ships with `TraMineR`.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(biofam)
biofam.lab <- c("Parent", "Left", "Married", "Left+Marr",
                "Child", "Left+Child", "Left+Marr+Child", "Divorced")
biofam.slab <- c("P","L","M","LM","C","LC","LMC","D")
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam, 10:25, labels=biofam.lab, states = biofam.slab)

## Computing an OM dissimilarity matrix using INDELSLOG costs
costs <- seqcost(biofam.seq, method="INDELSLOG")
biofam.om <- seqdist(biofam.seq, method="OM", indel=costs$indel,
     sm=costs$sm)

## Representative set using the neighborhood density criterion
##  The neighborhood radius (pradius) is set as 
##  20% of the maximal distance, and the number of representatives
##  is chosen so as 75% of the sequences lie in the neighborhood of
##  a representative.
biofam.rep <- seqrep(biofam.seq, diss=biofam.om, criterion="density",
     coverage=.75, pradius=.2)

rep.idx <- attr(biofam.rep, "Index") ## indexes of repreentatives
rep.seq <- biofam.seq[rep.idx,]
dist.to.rep <-attr(biofam.rep, "Distances")
min.dist <- apply(dist.to.rep, 1, min, na.rm=TRUE)

discrep <- dissvar(biofam.om)
q <- 2*discrep
outliers <- which(min.dist> q)

## Plot of representatives and outliers
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
seqiplot(rep.seq, sortv="from.end", with.legend=FALSE, 
     border=NA, main="Representatives")
seqIplot(biofam.seq[outliers,], sortv="from.end", with.legend=FALSE,
     main="Outliers")
seqlegend(biofam.seq)
```

[image: plot of representatives and outliers]

Here, we see that there are 29 outliers (out of 2000 sequences). They include people who continue staying with their parents after getting married, who live with a child without getting married, who marry early and don't have children, and people who divorce.