# Detecting outlier points WITHOUT clustering, if we know that the data points form clusters of size $>10$

Tags: self-study, clustering, outliers

I'm having a final exam on Data Warehouses and Data Mining (Computer Science bachelor), and the professor recommends some extra exercises on his web-page, as extra material for studying before the exam.

In them, lies the following exercise, among others:

> In the following image, we can see three well-defined clusters and two
>   outliers. Describe the application of a technique which will detect
>   the outlier points without performing clustering, *however knowing
>   that all [non-outlier] points form clusters of size $>10$.*

[image: Yes, I drew this because the book image was awful]

Now, I don't know of any techniques that detect outliers without actually performing clustering, and I looked up the relevant chapters in the teaching book to see if any algorithms or techniques are described. I found a total of one (1!) pages, that briefly states:

> To remove outliers, we calculate the sum of distances of a point
>   towards all others. To calculate the distances, we can use Mahalanobis
>   Distance.

After which, the writer of the book (also my class professor) casually lists the following result plot, with no explanation on how it was produced (***note that the data in this plot are irrelevant from the exercise above, and are from an earlier book example***):

[image]

And that's it. It doesn't even list a formula or objective function to calculate Mahalanobis distance, which I had to look up on Wikipedia.

Apart from that, the exercise does not mention **standard deviation**, so the two prominent results I got from `stats.stackexchange` are of no use ([this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38001/detecting-outliers-using-standard-deviations) and [also this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346922/detecting-outlier-sequences-in-clusters)).

I'm frustrated because this is supposed to be `Exercise 2`, which should mean "easy" and "introductionary", and should require a minimal description and effort to solve, but here I stand stumped.

Does anyone know of any algorithms that do this, relevant to us knowing in-advance that the points form clusters of $size>10$? Any help or pointers towards the right direction would be greatly appreciated. My first thoughts was to describe applying `k-means` or `DBSCAN`, but these are actual clustering techniques, and the exercise calls for just outlier detection without clustering.

Comment: Hint: What does the distribution of the nearest-neighbor distance look like?

Comment: @whuber For every object, I could 1) Calculate the distance of it from all others 2) Find the 10 Minimums 3) Store them as outlier_scores. Yes, the two "real" outliers in the graph are going to have huge outlier_scores when compared to every other object, but how can I correctly generalize and say "Yeah their outlier_scores is `x` times bigger, therefore they're outliers" ?

Comment: For each object, compute the distance to its nearest neighbor.  Draw a picture of the distribution of these numbers: the presence of the outliers will be abundantly clear--and no "clustering" is involved in this process.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. Would I also be correct in thinking that a better pointer of `being an outlier or not` would be a sum/average of the distances to the 10 closest neighbors, not just one?

Comment: The problem with that characterization is that "10" was derived from your visual assessment of clustering.  The distribution of nearest-neighbor distances identifies outliers regardless of what value you take as the threshold.

Comment: @Whuber, but would two outliers that happen to be close (although not likely) be outliers or a cluster? If there is some auxiliary way that allows us to state that a cluster must be larger than 10 points then we can use this to our advantage.

Comment: @whuber I understand your point, but keep in mind that it was a given, in the exercise, that we start off with the knowledge that the data forms clusters of $size >10$, as I mentioned in the question. That's where I got the 10.

Comment: @Martijn Consideration of the nearest-neighbor distance can identify only isolated outliers, of course.  To find small clusters of outliers you would need to extend this approach to a k-nearest-neighbors analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Outliers in that data set can easily be found with

- nearest neighbor outlier detection (KNN)
- local outlier factor (LOF)
- local outlier probabilities (LOOP)

And many more. Choose a small k value, less than 10. For example k=1 for the first, or k=5 for the others.